# Using flexbox, menubar pushes rest of body off center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am aiming to place a text box in right in the center of the page, and three buttons below it. Now I hope to add a menu bar on top with a few buttons to the right, but when I use flex to align the menu to the top right, it pushes the text/buttons to the left. If I don't align the menu to the right, everything stays centered. I think it's how I'm using flex properties, but I'm not sure how I can ensure the two sections don't knock each other out of alignment.

```css
.form-buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.search_btn {
  width: 150px;
  border: 0;
}

.search_txt {
  width: 400px;
}

.topnav {
  /*display: flex;*/
  justify-content: flex-end;
  gap: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>



<form class="search" action="https://calculator">
  <input class="search_txt" type="text">
  <div class="form-buttons">
    <input class="search_btn" type="submit" value="value">
    <input class="search_btn" type="submit" value="average">
    <input class="search_btn" type="submit" value="average2">

  </div>
  <!-- <input class="search_btn" type="submit" value="perimeter"> -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your use of `flex` properties. The issue was the `float: right` on your `.topnav` element. When you added that, it floats the element next to the `form` element. What you need to do is add `clear: both` on the form (`.search`).

Also, you had a few `gap` properties, which will do nothing for flex items (`gap` is for CSS Grid elements), and you can remove the `justify-content` property on the `topnav` since it's not a flex parent.

```css
.form-buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  clear: both;
}

.search_btn {
  width: 150px;
  border: 0;
}

.search_txt {
  width: 400px;
}

.topnav {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>



<form class="search" action="https://calculator">
  <input class="search_txt" type="text">
  <div class="form-buttons">
    <input class="search_btn" type="submit" value="value">
    <input class="search_btn" type="submit" value="average">
    <input class="search_btn" type="submit" value="average2">

  </div>
  <!-- <input class="search_btn" type="submit" value="perimeter"> -->
</form>
```

As the other answer by @David Huculak points out, you could just remove the `float: right` altogether and then uncomment the `display: flex`

Comment: thank you so much! I understand the issue now

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you had commented out the correct code. This should do the trick:

```css
.topnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @disinfor I tested it out in codesandbox, seems to be working: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-shape-8txk3

Comment: Ah, I see what you did now. The root of the problem isn't the `display: flex` it was `float: right` and not clearing the `form` element. Yours will work, but you should probably include more code and explain why then.

Comment: Deleted my original comment after noticing you removed the `float` from the CSS.

Comment: @David Huculak Thank you so much